# How to replace only certain commas with dots in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, data-cleaning

I have some data in a column of a Pandas DataFrame where some of the numbers have a thousandth comma, as well as european style decimal comma. For example:

```
40,910,27
3,479.29
34,561.09
132,634,98
```

I have tried using :

```
df['Orders'] = df['Orders'].replace(to_replace = ',', value = '.', regex = True)
```

But the issue is that this obviously replaces all commas with dots, so some numbers end up having two dots. Is there a way to remove the non-decimal commas only, and replace the actual decimal commas with a dot?

Comment: How many columns do you have? Is it just a fixed 2 column dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you need to replace only the last comma, so you can do:

```
s = pd.Series(['40,910,27', '3,479.29', '34,561.09', '132,634,98'], dtype='string')
res = s.str.replace(',(\d+)$', r'.\1', regex=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0     40,910.27
1      3,479.29
2     34,561.09
3    132,634.98
dtype: string
```

The regex:

- `',(\d+)$'` means match a comma that is followed by a group of digits till the end of the string.

The replacement:

- `'.\1'` a point and the first capture group (that is the groups digits after the last comma)

Answer (score 0):

1. split string ends with 2 digit, use `()` to keep the split partner left.
2. join the split list with '.'
3. strip the string '.' at end.

```
(s.str.split('[.,](\d{2})$')
     .str.join('.')
     .str.strip('.'))
```